# Get line number from Get-PSCallStack?

Tags: powershell

I want to add the line number to a message format method. Basically, this method is called to prepend useful information before it gets printed via Write-[Whatever level]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Posting and answering since I wasn't able to find the answer I wanted quite as fast as I hoped.

Best answer: `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptLineNumber`

The MSDN article on the [CallStackFrame class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.callstackframe_methods(v=vs.85).aspx) was very useful (and `Get-PSCallStack | Get-Member` for straightening out where the methods I saw people using that weren't in the CallStackFrame class were coming from), but I was confused why I didn't see many people using this property. The other solutions I found online were:

`(get-pscallstack)[0].Location`

`$lineNum = ((get-pscallstack)[$n].Location -split " line ")[1]`

However, they're not as clean or exact.

Comment: No problem @sodawillow, glad someone could benefit :]